# unable to get data via broadcast from service to fragment

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I want to receive data sent form service to my fragment. I am sending the data from my service:

```
Intent i1 = new Intent("com.iot.bcrec.randomreceive");
i1.putExtra("values",String.valueOf(value));
//Here value is the data i want to pass
sendBroadcast(i1);
```

In my fragment I have use broadcast receiver:

```
 BroadcastReceiver qReciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String s1 = intent.getStringExtra("values");
        float flag = Float.parseFloat(s1);
        Log.i(TAG,"fragment = "+s1);
        //method which uses the received data
        addEntry(flag);
    }
};
```

By examining log value I found that my fragment doesn't receive any value via broadcast. As while debugging my code, I didn't find any log.
I have registered my Broadcast:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, 
    false);
....
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.iot.bcrec.randomreceive"); 
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver
(qReciever,filter);
    return view;
}
```

And unregistered it:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver
    (qReciever);
}
```

The code compiles and runs fine without any error.

I don't know what is the problem the same code runs fine giving the desired results, when I sent the broadcast to the activity, but doesn't work on the fragment. Anybody who has faced the same problem ??

Comment: Receivers registered on `LocalBroadcastManager` can only get broadcasts sent with `LocalBroadcastManager`. In your `Service`, you're sending that broadcast on `Context`. Change that to `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(i1);`.

Comment: @Mike thanks for pointing it man. I was wondering for like hours because of this stupid mistake. Now my app runs just fine.